# Google AppScript to move row when date is entered

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet wherein there is a checkbox column (26) and a date column (27). There are two active scripts that effect this tab.

1. When the checkbox (26) is clicked I have a script that auto-adds the date (27).
2. When the checkbox (26) is clicked I have a script that moves the row to another tab.

The problem I am having is that sometimes the row is moved before the date is added. (the script pasted below)

How do I alter script #2 such that the row moves when any date is added to Col 27 instead of when the checkbox is clicked in Col 26?

Any help is much appreciated:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 26 or 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "APPROVAL QUEUE" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COMPLETED ORDERS");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Would it be possible to combine the two scripts and have the addition of the date and the move in the same script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making this function not an onEdit one, but regular. 
And then call this function in your onEdit script that puts in the date. So it completes putting in the date, and then runs the script to move the row of data. You could even put an Utilities.sleep(1000) (1000 microseconds is one second) to delay the script moving the row.

Comment: Sorry for being so basic about this - but where in the code above should I insert  Utilities.sleep(1000)

Comment: If you rename the function, for example 'function moveRow()', you can put it on the very end of your onEdit script that fills in the date.
Like 
.....
Utilities.sleep(1000);
moveRow
....
}

Answer (score 0):

### It is not allowed to have two simple `onEdit` triggers in one project

1. You need to merge the code of the two scripts into one two avoid conflicting behavior
2. In order to avoid the row being copied before  the date is inserted - use [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Sample how to implement two functionalities in one:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 26 or 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "APPROVAL QUEUE" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == true) {
    s.getRange(row, 27).setValue(new Date());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COMPLETED ORDERS");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    //the following line is not necessary since you moved rather than copied that range
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for putting that together, replaced the old script with this one and disabled the time stamp script. When I tried to run it unfortunately nothing happened (the row didnt move and the timestamp didnt add).

Comment: Did you run it manually or triggered by an edit? I recommend you for troubleshooting to implement logs outside and inside the `if` statement. You can view them under `View->Executions` to understand what is wrong.